# React Admin Layout Component From Scratch

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-admin

I want to implement a customized Layout for react-admin. I've tried to use their documentation 'https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Theming.html#using-a-custom-layout'
But it didn't work well ( for example we didn't have `theme` in our component). There is a broken link in the documentation that says you can use it for customizing :(.

I've implemented something right now that works fine right now but I don't know would work completely without problem/side-effects till the end of the project.

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { MuiThemeProvider, withStyles, createStyles} from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import appTheme from '../config/Theme'
import AppBar from './AppBar'
import Navbar from './Navbar'

const styles = (theme: any) => createStyles({
  appFrame: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    overflowX: 'auto',
  },
  content: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    flexGrow: 2,
    marginTop: '4em',
    padding: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
    paddingLeft: 5,
  },
  contentNoSidebar: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  root: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.default,
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    minHeight: '100vh',
    position: 'relative',
    zIndex: 1,
  },
})

class CustomLayout extends React.Component<any, any> {
  public render () {
    const {
      children,
      classes,
      logout,
      open,
      title,
    } = this.props
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={appTheme}>
        <div className={classes.root}>
          <div className={classes.appFrame}>
            <AppBar title={title} open={open} logout={logout} />
            <Navbar/>
            <main className={classes.contentNoSidebar}>
                <div className={classes.content}>
                    {children}
                </div>
            </main>
          </div>
        </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    )
  }
}
export default withStyles(styles)(CustomLayout)
```

I appreciate if you could help me in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see nothing wrong with this code sample. This is indeed the way to go to customize the Layout. Do you have any issue with it ?

Can you open an issue on the react-admin repository about the documentation broken link ?

Comment: thank you Gildas,
here is the documentation broken link :
https://screenshots.firefox.com/wWJf75LYVuksV4z1/marmelab.com
i will put it on repo too.